# Access database won't update from VB.NET

Tags: .net, ms-access, datagridview, connection

Could someone please help me figure out how to get VB.NET to update its connected MS ACCESS database?

MS Access 2013
Visual Studio 2012 (Framework 4.0)

**Problem:** My DataGrid will not update its source MS Access database upon hitting the "save" button. It just

Basically, I just set up my connection the standard way. Here is a very generic & basic version of my failed structure.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub StudentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StudentBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.StudentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TestdbDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TestdbDataSet.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.StudentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestdbDataSet.Student)

End Sub

End Class
```

This is just the system generated code from the setup wizard. I have spent the past 8 hours straight trying to fix this seemingly benign issue. I am just worn out.

Comment: Pedantic note: the problem has nothing to do with VB.NET. That's just the programming language you're using to call .NET components like System.Data.OleDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community,

After some additional research and a lot of trial & error, I have figured out how to get  vb.NET to update its MS ACCESS Database. Basically, you need to change one property of the imported database, and change the update command of the imported dataset. Here is a complete walkthrough of the steps.

►MS Access 2013

►Visual Studio 2012

►.NET Framework 4.5

(For best results, follow each step deliberately).

**Step 1: Create Sample MS Access Database**

- Table Name:** "Table A"
- Field 1: "ID" | [Autonumber Product Key]
- Field 2: "Title" | "Sample A", "Sample B", ... "Sample G"
- Field 3: "Val" | "a", "b", ..., "g"
- Save As: "SampleAccessDatabase.mdb"
- Close: Close MS Access

**Step 2: Open Visual Studio 2012 Project**

- New Project: Templates ► Visual Basic ► "Windows Form Application"

**Step 3: Connect to MS Access Database**

- Add New Data Source ► Database [Next>] ► Database [Next>] ► New Connection
- Add Connection Window: Data Source ► "Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB)"
- Add Connection Window: Database File Name ► Browse ► Grab "SampleAccessDatabase.mdb" file ► [Hit OK]
- Add Connection Window: [Hit OK] ► [Next>] ► [Hit Yes] ► [Next >]
- Choose Your Database Objects: Select "Table A" ► Finish

**Step 4: Place Control Objects**

- Data Sources: Grab "Table A" and place it on the "Form1" object

**Step 5: Change DataSet Property**

- Solution Explorer: Select "SampleAccessDatabase.mdb"
- Properties: Select "Copy To Output Directory" ► Change to **"Copy if newer"**

**Step 6: Change TableAdapter Update Command**

- Solution Explorer: Double-Click "SampleAccessDatabaseDataset.xsd"
- Pane: Select "Table ATableAdapter" Object in the middle pane
- Properties: Expand [Update Command] by clicking on dropdown menu and selecting [New]
- Update Command: Open [CommandText] by clicking on the ellipsis [...]
- Add Table: Select "Table A" and hit [Add]
- Query Builder: After the word **SET** type **"Field2=?"**. Hit Enter
- Query Builder: After the word **"WHERE"** type **"(Field1=?"**. [Hit OK]

**Step 7: Test it out**

- CTRL+F5: Change "Field2" to "1","2",..."7" ► Close Form/Application
- CTRL+F5: View updated DataGrid

That is it. Now, you can create your .NET Desktop application in Visual Studio 2012 with the ability to store & update data from your MS Access database (2013).

Comment: -1. I usually upvote self-answers, but your answer doesn't show what the problem was.

Comment: **"After some additional..., I have figured out how to get vb.NET to update its MS Access Database."** You're saying that my self-answer didn't define the problem that it was solving. Didn't the first sentence state that? Well, I'll take any suggestions you have. Based on google results, several other people have had this problem and I figured this post could serve as an aide to them. **That is it. Now, you can create your .NET Desktop application in Visual Studio 2012 with the ability to store & update data from your MS Access database (2013)."**

Answer (score 0):

if you start your aplication using start button on visual studio, it will copy new database to your aplication file (which stored in "/debug/youraplication.exe" ). 
try to direct execute youraplication.exe in debug folder, and then try to insert/delete/update your database using your aplication, and close your aplication, now open databasae.accdb which stored in folder debug, now you can see your database contained your input

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem still and can't figure it out expect to "Force" the update as you did. 
So far it's seems every dataset I have that I have at least one field I am filling programmatically and there is no associated control the users can edit that field on the form, the dataset doesn't allow update/delete, only new and insert.
I could be on the wrong track though.

Answer (score 0):

This fix the problem:

Step 5: Change DataSet Property

Solution Explorer: Select "SampleAccessDatabase.mdb"
Properties: Select "Copy To Output Directory" ► Change to "Copy if newer"

My problem is app always copy new database to debug folder of app...